# How to update symbolic links during upgrading (macOS)

Tags: orientdb

[Documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Tutorial-Installation.html#upgrading) says

> If you installed from binary downloads, repeat the download process above and update any symbolic links or shortcuts to point to the new directory.

How to do that (macOS) ? 
[Edit] wouldn't be possible to just copy the "databases" folder inside the new orientdb folder ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the documentation wants to say is that you can :

- Have a symbolic link which point to your database folder
- Copy the database folder into your new orientdb folder.

Answer (score 0):

On osx you can use brew to install orientdb. We work to keep the version updated to latest stable.

Comment: Trying brew...  I used to get realtime log, error and feedback from the server through the Terminal window when orientdb was launch from the server.sh; would it be possible to get it back ?

Comment: Of course. If you want to run it on a terminal interactively `/usr/local/Cellar/orientdb/2.2.18/libexec/bin/server.sh`

Comment: BTW, my preferred way to play with different versions of OrientDB on my laptop is through Docker